# ngb-progressbar styling in Angular project

Tags: angular, progress-bar, ng-bootstrap

I want to add `ngb-progressbar` with custom styling in my Angular Project. I tried it with `ng-bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

Import `ngb-progressbar` in `app.module.ts` file

```js
import { NgbProgressbarModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Now edit the *HTML* file

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <ngb-progressbar
      type="success"
      [max]="100"
      [value]="25"
      height="30px"
      [striped]="true"
      [animated]="true"
    ><span class="skill"
    >HTML <i class="val">25%</i></span
    ></ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
  <p>
    <ngb-progressbar
      type="info"
      [max]="100"
      [value]="50"
      height="30px"
      [striped]="true"
      [animated]="true"
    ><span class="skill"
    >CSS <i class="val">50%</i></span
    ></ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
  <p>
    <ngb-progressbar
      type="warning"
      [max]="100"
      [value]="75"
      height="30px"
      [striped]="true"
      [animated]="true"
    ><span class="skill"
    >JavaScript <i class="val">75%</i></span
    ></ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
  <p>
    <ngb-progressbar
      type="danger"
      [max]="100"
      [value]="100"
      height="30px"
      [striped]="true"
      [animated]="true"
    ><span class="skill"
    >Angular 9 <i class="val">100%</i></span
    ></ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
</div>
```

This will give you the look-like output
[image]